# Clip Shapefiles via Iteration in QGIS Python Script

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-modeler

I have two polygon shapefiles with several objects. Each object in both shapefiles has a given ID number. Now I want to clip the object with ID=1 in Shapefile A with the object with ID=1 in Shapefile B.

However each shapefile has about 5000 objects, so I would like to create a Python script via the QGIS graphical modeler. I know how to use the graphical modeler to clip objects and stuff, but I cannot find any iteration option within the modeler. Is there an option to do so or how can I implement an iteration directly into the script to get the wanted clip results?

In the end I would like to have one new shapefile with all the clips.